# sort from a list of data which is due in next 12 hrs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data which has a "Due" column which is in the format of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm. I am looking to sort this data to list only the rows with specific columns which is due in the next 12 hours.

Comment: Thank you. Used Datediff to fix my problem.

DateDiff2 = DateDiff("h", Open_Sheet_Array(i, 12), Now) ' Due

Answer (score 0):

See if this does what you want it to do - after changing it to suit your spreadsheet.

Also, left as this is, you'd have to run this macro manually to see an updated sorting based on the current time.  You'd have to set this macro to run once a certain time interval has passed - say every hour.  This will likely include writing a line of code such as `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "test"` if you want to run the macro below every 1 minute.  I'll let you experiment with that.

```
Public Sub test()

Dim list() As String

RightNow = Now

For i = 0 To 11 'iterate loop 12 times (includes 0) for each of the next 12 hours.
    ReDim Preserve list(i)
    list(i) = Format(DateAdd("h", 1, RightNow), "m/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
    RightNow = DateAdd("h", 1, RightNow)
Next

On Error Resume Next 'used for the sake of the next line if there are not filters and all data is already being shown - otherwise the next line would cause an error.
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'removes all filters in activesheet, so that next line will be able to delete the 5th custom list (if there is only one custom list).

Application.DeleteCustomList (5) 'delete old list array (assumes that this array's custom list index is always 5.

Application.AddCustomList Array(list()) 'add array, list, as custom list that can be used to sort data.

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=5, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used a Datediff function to get my data sorted.